# Apache Spark worker executor EXITED with exit status 1

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark standalone setup (v 1.4.1) with 3 workers.

I have an application that read a stream from a Kafka Topic elaborate data and store it in another Kafka Topic.

Last night the application fell down and all worker was down.

The worker's logs report like the following:

```
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" "-cp" "/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/../conf/:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" "-Xms1024M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=52180" "-DenabledWorkerLog=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=54330" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@driverHost:52180/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "24279" "--hostname" "worker2" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-20160201182749-0007" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@worker2:57853/user/Worker"
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160201182749-0007/24279/stdout with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160201182749-0007/24279/stderr with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160129184621-0001/1430 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160129184621-0001/1431 for stream-elaboration
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" "-cp" "/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/../conf/:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" "-Xms1024M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=57297" "-DenabledWorkerLog=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=54326" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@driverHost:57297/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "1431" "--hostname" "worker2" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-20160129184621-0001" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@worker2:57853/user/Worker"
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160129184621-0001/1431/stdout with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:10 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160129184621-0001/1431/stderr with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160201182749-0007/24279 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160201182749-0007/24280 for stream-elaboration
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" "-cp" "/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/../conf/:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" "-Xms1024M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=52180" "-DenabledWorkerLog=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=54330" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@driverHost:52180/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "24280" "--hostname" "worker2" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-20160201182749-0007" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@worker2:57853/user/Worker"
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160201182749-0007/24280/stdout with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160201182749-0007/24280/stderr with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160129184621-0001/1431 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160129184621-0001/1432 for stream-elaboration
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" "-cp" "/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/../conf/:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" "-Xms1024M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=57297" "-DenabledWorkerLog=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=54326" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@driverHost:57297/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "1432" "--hostname" "worker2" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-20160129184621-0001" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@worker2:57853/user/Worker"
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160129184621-0001/1432/stdout with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO FileAppender: Rolling executor logs enabled for /dati/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160129184621-0001/1432/stderr with daily rolling
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160201182749-0007/24280 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
16/02/04 21:02:11 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160201182749-0007/24281 for stream-elaboration
```

at the end of the log:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp291507283-42"
Exception in thread "qtp291507283-37" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "ExecutorRunner for app-20160201182749-0007/29488" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkWorker-scheduler-1"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "qtp291507283-38" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "JMX server connection timeout 81" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JMX server connection timeout 81"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "sparkWorker-10"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp291507283-40"
Exception in thread "qtp291507283-35" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"

Exception in thread "qtp291507283-39" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "qtp291507283-41" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "qtp291507283-36" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" 

....
```

Running:

```
ps aux | grep "worker"
```

the process is still active, but I can't see it on sparkUI.

Why are worker executor restart so frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs show multiple `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` messages, which means your executors throw errors which cause them to exit.

This error means your program spends too much time running GC (see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)). To resolve this - you can try one of these paths:

- The brute-force way would be disabling this safety by adding `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` to your executors' JVM options, but it might leave your application doing mostly GC, hence running very slowly
- Analyze your job's memory usage and optimize it - your code might be consuming more memory than needed, forcing the GC to work too hard
- Tune your memory settings - for example, if you can increase heap space for the executors, pressure on GC might be reduced

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially running out of memory to run the process smoothly. Options that come to mind:

1. Specify more memory like you mentioned, try something in between like -Xmx512m first.
2. Debug your code to find out possibilities of memory leaks.

> Why are worker executor restart so frequently?

You are using Spark Streaming which is built on Spark, so it enjoys the same fault-tolerance for worker nodes that means if the worker goes down due to some unexpected error as in your case Spark engine will attempt to restart it.